# Unable to create ACR container resource trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-container-registry

Having trouble setting up a pipeline that is triggered by pushing an image to an ACR repository.
No matter how i try to define a trigger i always get the error:

> Configuring the trigger failed, edit and save the pipeline again

As far as i can tell there's no more details as to what the problem is.
Saving without a trigger entry seams fine.

Here's my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  containers:
  - container: 'MyContainer'
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: 'My-ServicePrincipal'
    resourceGroup: 'My-App-Development'
    registry: 'myappregistry.azurecr.io'
    repository: 'myrepository'
    image: 'myrepository' 
    trigger: 
      enabled: true
      tags:
        include: 
        - latest

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempt in my YAML pipeline with the same configurations like as yours, and get the same issue.

However, after I changed the configurations like as below, the issue disappeared, and the trigger can work well as expected.

```yaml
trigger: none

resources:
  containers:
  - container: MyACR
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: {name of ARM connection}
    resourceGroup: {name of resource group}
    registry: {name of ACR}
    repository: {name of repository}
    image: {name of image}
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      tags:
        include:
        - latest
. . .
```

OR

```yaml
trigger: none

resources:
  containers:
  - container: MyACR
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: {name of ARM connection}
    resourceGroup: {name of resource group}
    registry: {name of ACR}
    repository: {name of repository}
    trigger:
      tags:
        include:
        - latest
. . .
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work as far as saving the pipeline without the error message. Unfortunately its still not triggering if i push to the latest tag.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a bit old, but I have to share this:  Spent yesterday trying to solve this with one of my team mates, and he found that our Azure subscription was a "Standard" subscription where we were capped to 10 Webhooks for the Azure Container Repository.  We upgraded to Premium and things started working fine again.  So my 2 cents worth is to go to the Container registry in the Azure portal, then under the "Services" category you will find a "Webhooks" menu item and work from there to find any possible problems.

Using the Azure Powershell console in the Azure portal, you can see what your limits are by running the following command:

```
Get-AzContainerRegistryUsage -ResourceGroupName "[INSERT_ACR_RG_NAME_HERE]" -RegistryName "[INSERT_ACR_NAME_HERE]"
```

In my results I used to get 10 for the limit, now I get 500 since our upgrade to Premium.

```
CurrentValue Limit        Name                       Unit
------------ -----        ----                       ----
11           500          Webhooks                   Count
```

If you find that there is no webhook for the image in the container repository in question, the webhook will be automatically recreated when you change the yml file that implements the trigger.  In my case, I changed the trigger enabled flag in the yml file to false, then back to true again, and the webhook magically appeared.

Comment: You my sir, are a genius!! Been wasting several hours trying all the permutations and combinations in the pipeline since it was bloody working initially and stopped working for no rhyme or reason! 